# How to store huge amount of NSStrings for comparison purpose

Tags: objective-c, database, file, nsstring, save

I am writing a (linguistic) Morphology Mac Application. I often have to check if the Words in a given Text are in a huge List of Words (~1.000.000).

My Question is: How do i store these Lists ?

1. I use a .txt File to store the Words and create an NSSet from this File, which survives as long as the Application is launched.
2. I use a Database like SQLite.

Some points:

- I think the focus should be on speed, because the analysis is triggered by the user and this comparisons make the largest part of the computation.
- The Lists may change via updates.
- I used CoreData and MySQL before, so (i think) i could realize both.

I have read a lot about the pro/cons of Database vs. File but i never thought its my usecase.

I dont know if its relevant which technik i use, because the size of these Files is relatively small (~20MB) and even with a lot of supported Languages, only 3-4 of this files will be loaded into memory at the same time.

Thanks! Danke!

Comment: I imagine CoreData could do the job; Apple has stated that it is extremely optimized. I would test it with CoreData and see if you are getting adequate performance

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! I was hoping to avoid own tests because i dont know how well they'll scale but now i hope the database approach isn't to far-fetched !